# Using same jQuery function on different data based on element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dry

I'm creating a virtual piano on codepen as practice, and am trying to find a way to write one jQuery function that will play a different sound based on which key is clicked.  I created all the keys as list items in an ordered list, and gave them each an id based on what note they are.  I've figured out how to play the sound based on the note pressed, and I technically could copy the code for each note, but I wanted to practice making my code more compact.  This is what I have so far:

```
$('li')
    .mousedown(function(){
    $('#noteC')[0].play();
  })
    .mouseup(function(){
    $('#noteC')[0].pause(); 
    $('#noteC').prop('currentTime',0);
  })
```

I tried adding `var c = $('#noteC')[0]` into the script and `<li class="ivory" id="C" data-note='c'>C</li>`. I thought there might be some way of triggering it by linking each sound to its list item, so that when the list item is clicked on, JS knows which sound to play. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I also added <li class="ivory" id="C" data-note='c'>C</li> into the HTML. Got cut off the question for some reason

Comment: if I understand correctly, inside of  your handlers you can do `document.getElementById('note' + this.id).play() / .pause()`

Answer (score 1):

Many options here but one simple way:

Add a data attribute to each `li` like: `data-note="noteC"`.

Then:

```
$('li').mousedown(function() {
   $('#'+$(this).data('note'))[0].play();
}).mouseup(function() {
   $('#'+$(this).data('note'))[0].pause();
   $('#'+$(this).data('note')).prop('currentTime',0);
});
```

EDIT: based on your `data-note="c"` attribute, select the right note like:

```
$('#note'+$(this).data('note').toUpperCase()) //etc
```

Comment: You're correct. Read more on jquery selectors. I just used the `$(this).data('note')` to get a string to create the selector